# File transfer plugin for ios does not work

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-code, ionic3

I am able to use file transfer plugin in android and able to download file but it does not work in ios i am using this.file.documentsDirectory; for ios and for android this.file.externalDataDirectory; and i am using

```
 <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
```

in `config.xml`. I had used following for ios but it does not work

```
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />
<preference name="iosExtraFilesystems" value="library,library-nosync,documents,documents-nosync,cache,bundle,root" />
```

It will be great if any body can help regarding this.

Comment: How is it not working? What do you see?

Comment: it does not toast path when i run app in device do i need any permission or preference in config.xml thank you for your reply

Comment: If you remove debug with Safari, do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: no i m not getting any output not even in toast also could not find why it happens like this.

Comment: So to be clear, you tested with Remote Debug and Safari?

Comment: I am new to ionic how to test with remote debug and safari can you please help me.

Comment: See: https://developer.telerik.com/featured/a-concise-guide-to-remote-debugging-on-ios-android-and-windows-phone/